# pythonで2次元配列を用いた条件分岐について

Tags: python

2次元配列liがあり

```
li=[[0,0,0],
    [0,2,0],
    [0,1,0],
    [0,0,0],
    [0,3,0],
    [0,0,0]]
```

2次元配列liの中央の列の数字(0,2,1,0,3,0)に、
(質問1)１つでも0より上の数字がある場合の判定、
(質問2)すべて0の判定、
をif文で行いたいです。

(質問3)また、中央の列の数字で、0より上の数字が最後は何行目に出現したか(今回の場合は3が出現した5番目)も知りたいです。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 皆さん、質問が三つあると解釈されたようで、それに従って質問も編集されています。私は全てを一度に行ないたい、という一つの質問だと思ったのでロールバックしたのですが、すでに皆さんの回答がついていたので、またもどしました。まあ、どちらにせよ大差ない有意義な回答が得られそうですが。

Answer (score 1):

全ての判定を一度に行ないたいのだと解釈しました。
「中央の列」は「行」の2番目の要素(インデックスでは1)の事だとします。

「最後は何行目に出現したか」だけ分かればよいので、リストは末尾から見ていっています。
見つかったら、そこでループを抜けます。
リストのインデックスは0から始まるので、行数の表示にはインデックスに1足しています。

```python
found_target = False
for i in range(len(li)-1, -1, -1):
    if li[i][1] > 0:
        print("最後尾ターゲットは", li[i][1], "で、", i+1, "行目")
        found_target = True
        break
if not found_target:
    print("ターゲットなし")
```

イテレータ版

```python
import itertools as it
target = list(it.islice(((i, v[1]) for i,v in enumerate(reversed(li)) if v[1]>0), 1))
if target:
    print("最後尾ターゲットは", target[0][1], "で、", len(li)-target[0][0], "行目")
else:
    print("ターゲットなし")
```

Answer (score 1):

(質問1)１つでも0より上の数字がある場合の判定

```
print sum(zip(*li)[1]) > 0
```

(質問2)すべて0の判定

```
print sum(zip(*li)[1]) == 0
```

(質問3)また、中央の列の数字で、0より上の数字が最後は何行目に出現したか

```
for i, e in reversed(list(enumerate(zip(*li)[1]))):
    if e > 0:
        print i+1, e
        break
else:
    print "not found"
```

質問3はもっといい答えがあると思います。

EDIT: 他の方の回答から得たヒントを組み合わせ。

```
center = zip(*li)[1]
# Q1
print any(map(lambda x: x > 0, center))
# Q2
print all(map(lambda x: x == 0, center))
```

Answer (score 1):

numpy を使ってみます。

```
import numpy as np

li=[[0,0,0], [0,2,0], [0,1,0], [0,0,0], [0,3,0], [0,0,0]]
x = np.array([tuple(l) for l in li],
             dtype=[('l','int'), ('c','int'), ('r', 'int')])

# 質問1
any(x['c'] > 0)

# 質問2
all(x['c'] == 0)

# 質問3
np.where(x['c'] > 0)[0][-1]
```

Comment: さすがnumpy。集合の操作はお手の物ですね。

Answer (score 1):

なるべく基本的な関数を用いて書いてみました.
質問３では見つからない場合-1を返します.

```
li=[[0,0,0],[0,2,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,0],[0,3,0],[0,0,0]]

# 質問1
print (reduce(lambda x,y: (y[1] > 0) or x,li,False))
# 質問2
print (reduce(lambda x,y: (y[1] > 0) and x,li,True))
# 質問3
print (reduce(lambda x,y: (lambda z : (x[0]+1,z)) (x[0] if y[1] > 0 else x[1]),li,(0,-1)))[1]
```

Comment: １、２は問題の定義をそのままコードにしたような、良い回答ですね。`center = zip(*li)[1]`などと２行目で定義すればlambdaの中の[1]が消えてさらに本質的な部分だけのコードになりますね。

Answer (score 0):

回答A

```
>>> # 質問1
>>> any_positive = False
>>> for x in li:
...     if x[1] > 0:
...         any_positive = True
...         break
... 
>>> any_positive
True

>>> # 質問2
>>> all_zero = True
>>> for x in li:
...     if x[1] != 0:
...         all_zero = False
...         break
... 
>>> all_zero
False

>>> # 質問3
>>> last_positive = None
>>> for idx, x in enumerate(li):
...     if x[1] > 0:
...         last_positive = idx
... 
>>> last_positive
4
```

回答B

```
>>> # 質問1
>>> any(x[1] > 0 for x in li)
True

>>> # 質問2
>>> all(x[1] == 0 for x in li)
False

>>> # 質問3
>>> [i for i, x in enumerate(li) if x[1] > 0][-1]
4
```

Comment: 私は、全ての判定を一度に行ないたい、という一つの質問だと思いました。質問の編集も一度ロールバックさせてもらったのですが、こちらの回答と整合しなくなるので、やはり戻しました。